# How to highlight the input button by clicking to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can't code jquery javascript therefore i have no idea how to highlight (border or background change) the submit button for a few seconds. I tried some of the scripts that have been shared on this platform but i wasn't lucky. What code do you suggest?

The button i need to highlight is `submitbtn`

and the button that needs to highlight it by click is `eventbtn`

I appreciate the help

Thanks

Edited: I Want to add class to the submit button once the button is clicked

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.submitbtn {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #407060;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.eventbtn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #A73D42;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbtn" id="form-submit" /></p>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="eventbtn" id="highlight"> <<<<<<<<<<< </button>
</div>
```

h

Comment: Please add your JS code so we can debug your attempt.

Comment: Did you consider to actually focus the button you are currently highlighting via a class? I suppose you want to indicate to the user where to interact next? Your highlight might not be visible on-screen, and to users with visual impairments, the highlight might not at all be perceivable, think screen reader users. Using `.focus()` solves both these issues, and actually already has an outline by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a class to the element you want to highlight. Then remove the class with the `setTimeout` function.

1. Add a class in CSS with a high specificity that contains all visible changes you want to apply. It does not matter what it is. It can be background, border, box-shadow...
2. In JS use an `eventListener` to listen to click-events on the button.
3. Apply the class you have specified in CSS with `classList.add()`.
4. Add a `setTimeout` function to remove the class after a specified time with `classList.remove()`

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```js
    // button element that will be clicked
var button = document.querySelector('button[class="eventbtn"]'),
    // element that should be highlighted
    input = document.querySelector('#form-submit'),
    // timer in ms
    timer = 2000;

// eventListener to execute the script on button click
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // adds a class to apply CSS changes for the highlighting
  input.classList.add('highlight');
  // timeout function
  setTimeout(function() {
    // removes the class after the timer has been reached
    input.classList.remove('highlight');
  }, timer);
})
```

```css
#form-submit.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* original CSS */
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.wpcf7-form-control.has-spinner.wpcf7-submit {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #407060;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.eventbtn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #A73D42;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit" id="form-submit" /></p>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="eventbtn" id="highlight">&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;</button>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
// button element that will be clicked
var $button = $('button[class="eventbtn"]'),
    // element that should be highlighted
    $input = $('#form-submit'),
    // timer in ms
    timer = 2000;

//Eventlistener looking for a click event
$button.click(function() {
  //adds a class for highlighting
  $input.addClass('highlight');
  //timeout function
  setTimeout(function() {
    //removes class for highlighting
    $input.removeClass('highlight');
  }, timer);
})
```

```css
#form-submit.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* original CSS */
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.wpcf7-form-control.has-spinner.wpcf7-submit {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #407060;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.eventbtn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #A73D42;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit" id="form-submit" /></p>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="eventbtn" id="highlight">&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;&#60;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there @tacoshy,

I get this error when i implement this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`. Does this work with jquery?

Comment: it is Javascript not jQuery. jQuery would work simliar but not the same as vanilla JS.

Comment: I added a jquery sample which I said works the same way just uses other functions as vanilla JS. `addEventListener` does not exist as such in jQuery. The jQuery equivalent is `.click()`

Answer (score 2):

The key is to remove the highlighting after a few seconds, this can be done with `setTimeout()` function:

```js
function highlight(id)
{
  clearTimeout(highlight.timer);
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  //highlight the button
  el.classList.add("highlighted");
  //remove highlight after 3sec
  highlight.timer = setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove("highlighted"), 3000);
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.wpcf7-form-control.has-spinner.wpcf7-submit {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #407060;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.eventbtn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #A73D42;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

/* added */
.highlighted
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em 1px red;
}
.wpcf7-submit {
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit" id="form-submit" /></p>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="eventbtn" id="highlight" onclick="highlight('form-submit')"> <<<<<<<<<<< </button>
</div>
```

Comment: while it is working you should sue an `eventListener` in modern programming instead of `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Agreed, this was just a simplified example not to overwhelm with complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean highlight `submitbtn` when clicking `eventbtn`?

Add a js to handle the click event, and then add highlight class to `submitbtn`.

```js
var eventbtn = document.getElementById('highlight');
var submitbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('submitbtn')[0];

eventbtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  submitbtn.classList.add('highlight');
});

eventbtn.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  submitbtn.classList.remove('highlight');
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.submitbtn {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #407060;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.eventbtn {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #A73D42;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #8beccc;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbtn" id="form-submit" /></p>
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="eventbtn" id="highlight"> <<<<<<<<<<< </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to answer with pure css by using `animation` and `keyframes`. My attempt only works the first time and once everytime after you change the target.

(Note that I'm not used to these properties so there may be a better way to do this)

```css
#form-submit{
  background-color: transparent;
}
@keyframes changeBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  99.999% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
#form-submit:target{
  animation: changeBackground 1s;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="form-submit" />
<a href="#form-submit">highlight</a>
<br>
<a href="#">change target</a>
```

Comment: This will only work once. While I'm a huge fan of CSS-only solutions it will not be helpful in long term. Espacially since you submitting a form you will require JS/jQuery anyways.

Comment: @tacoshy Indeed I didn't realize it would work once. I keep the answer that could be useful in some cases and hopefully I will find a way to make it work everytime !